# (Decoding) How does the pdf make the difference between a string and its operators?

Tags: pdf

I do not understand how the pdf makes the difference between a string and its syntax (BT, ET, Tm, T *, TD,...).. Parentheses are not 100% reliable. Is there a pattern or something I do not see?

[image]

How does it make the difference between:

[(**Hello world !**)]

[(**Hello**) 45 (**the**) 45 (**world**)] 
-> 45 is the position of the string on the document

[(**Hel(lo**) 45 (**the**) 45 (**wor)ld**)]
-> It can not count the parenthesis because some does not close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the examples you showed:

- `[(Hello world !)]` is an array (rectangular braces) containing a single string (round brackets) containing `Hello world !`.
- `[(Hello) 45 (the) 45 (world)]` is an array (rectangular braces) containing three strings and two numbers: `Hello`, 45, `the`, 45, `world`.
- `[(Hel(lo) 45 (the) 45 (wor)ld)]` is an array (rectangular braces) containing a single string (round brackets) containing `Hel(lo) 45 (the) 45 (wor)ld` as text.

The third item might surprise you, but simply read the PDF specification ISO 32000-1:

> A *literal string* shall be written as an arbitrary number of characters enclosed in parentheses. Any characters may appear in a string except unbalanced parentheses (LEFT PARENHESIS (28h) and RIGHT PARENTHESIS (29h)) and the backslash (REVERSE SOLIDUS (5Ch)) ... Within a literal string, the REVERSE SOLIDUS is used as an escape character.

*(ISO 32000-1 section 7.3.4.2 Literal Strings)*

Thus, **balanced** parentheses (a balanced pair opening before closing obviously) are verbatim allowed in a string!

If you happen to want to write a string with unbalanced brackets, you still have the option to escape them using a backslash.